# ERROR: Can't find the archive-keyring

Tags: debian, apt, debian-lenny, debian-squeeze

I'm trying to upgrade my Debian Lenny to Squeeze. I've replaced the word lenny to squeeze in sources.list and ran

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But after a while, I get this error

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up debian-archive-keyring (2010.08.28) ...
ERROR: Can't find the archive-keyring
Is the ubuntu-keyring package installed?
dpkg: error processing debian-archive-keyring (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debian-archive-keyring
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried to install `apt-get -f install debian-archive-keyring` and I got the same error. Then I tried to install `apt-get -f install ubuntu-keyring` and I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ubuntu-keyring is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package ubuntu-keyring has no installation candidate
```

Maybe I have the wrong sources in my sources.list:

```
deb    ftp://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages  squeeze          main contrib non-free
deb    ftp://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security  squeeze/updates  main contrib non-free

deb     http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/  squeeze  main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/  squeeze  main non-free contrib

deb     http://security.debian.org/  squeeze/updates  main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/  squeeze/updates  main contrib non-free
```

Hope anyone can help me,

thx,
tux

---

Thank you both for the answers.
@mailq
I also was wondering why there is an Ubuntu package missing/wrong. I'm running a Debian Lenny on my server, and tried to upgrade to squeeze. So, I replaced the words `lenny` with `squeeze` in my `sources.list`. And this is, what comes out: Some Ubuntu errors (???). The first sources are the local sources of my provider and second sources are, as Gilles said, the official (but slower) sources of Debian.

@Gilles
Here is the output of the commands:

```
# lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid

# type apt-key
apt-key is /usr/bin/apt-key

# dpkg -s apt
Package: apt
Status: install ok installed
Priority: important
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 5488
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.7.25.3ubuntu7
Replaces: libapt-pkg-dev (<< 0.3.7), libapt-pkg-doc (<< 0.3.7)
Provides: libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6-4.8
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0)
Recommends: ubuntu-keyring
Suggests: aptitude | synaptic | wajig, dpkg-dev, apt-doc, bzip2, lzma, python-apt
Conffiles:
 /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove 6154750d39a78704b5bbf6fafd65ada7
 /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu 078b96538a377743bee0f554eb5b2fc6
 /etc/logrotate.d/apt 179f2ed4f85cbaca12fa3d69c2a4a1c3
 /etc/cron.daily/apt 3528ddf873535d4c268d83e73e85dc79
Description: Advanced front-end for dpkg
 This is Debian's next generation front-end for the dpkg package manager.
 It provides the apt-get utility and APT dselect method that provides a
 simpler, safer way to install and upgrade packages.
 .
 APT features complete installation ordering, multiple source capability
 and several other unique features, see the Users Guide in apt-doc.
Original-Maintainer: APT Development Team <deity@lists.debian.org>
```

I only wanted to upgrade to Debian Squeeze, and I don't know how this Ubuntu stuff happens. A new installation isn't a good idea, because I'm running this server in production and don't want some downtime.

So, any further ideas?

thx,
tux

Comment: I finally come to the point to reinstall my system. Something in the update process went terrible wrong. 4 hours of work, but now everything is up to date and ok ;)

Answer (score 1):

The message “Is the ubuntu-keyring package installed?” comes from the `apt-key` program, which manages keyrings for APT. You evidently have the `apt-key` program from Ubuntu, not from Debian. Since the `apt-key` program is part of the `apt` package, there's something deeply wrong here. Are you sure this machine has Debian installed, and not Ubuntu? Check the output of `lsb_release -irc` (if `lsb_release` is present) or the version of the `base-files` package. Also check where your `apt-key` program is coming from: `type apt-key`, `dpkg -s apt`.

If you have Ubuntu, you can't upgrade to Debian (or vice versa). The two distributions use the same package format and have many packages in common, but there are enough difference that it would take some effort to support such cross-distribution upgrades, and there is hardly anyone interested in expending such effort. So if you have an older Ubuntu release (hardy, maybe?), keep it, upgrade to a new Ubuntu, or reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu?! What do ubuntu-keyrings have to do with Debian?

Eliminate the first both lines in the sources.list. Or the other four. But don't list them twice.

Comment: Indeed, that `ubuntu-keyring` message shouldn't come up on a Debian. On the other hand, there's nothing wrong with having more than one mirror for the same distribution in `sources.list`. It's a standard configuration when you have a partial local mirror, for instance (hit the local mirror first, and fall back to the full official mirror over a slow link).